# Email Signature (Mobile-friendly specially for Gmail App)

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to create an email signature specially for Gmail App. Unfortunately, media queries are not compatible for Gmail app. So i tried learning *fluid hybrid* method from http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919 to create an email signature that is mobile friendly. The link below indicates just part of the sample.

http://jsbin.com/supixiquji/edit?html,css,output

So the problem is, when I tried stretching the window to be smaller in jsbin ( which resulted in lesser width) .

a) The first part with lots of words automatically readjusted to fit with the smaller width but for

b) second part with twitter, fb and googleplus logo. When i tried stretching it, the icons do not readjust based on the smaller width and went to the next line instead of staying on the same line with the wwe.com.

Please do help if anyone knows how to solve the problem so that even if the window is stretched to the minimum width, the icons will still stick on the same line. (which could prove to be mobile friendly too)

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to do it would be to use Font Awesome icons and set the font with with vw

```
font-size:4vw;
```

Doing this will reduce the icon size depending on the Width.

OR

Why don't you try keeping the content in a Table. And give the table width in percentage. And Use media queries to place them as required.

OR

You can have 2 different tables for different screen size. And switch visibility using media queries.